# CentOS Invalid maximum heap size for .exe program

Tags: java, centos7

im using a VM with minimal installed CentOS 7. Im quite new with linux and CentOs. My Java version:

```
java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_232"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_232-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.232-b09, mixed mode)
```

When I try running a java based application (a .exe) I get the following error, this Java application should be running with Java8, in fact it was running last time the VM was on (last friday) today (sunday) when a turned on again it gives the error:

```
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx1g
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I tried the following commands:

```
java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M
```

[result of above command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKpzy.png)

and

```
java -Xmx2048M -d64
```

[results of the second command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5IJ1.png)

But as you see I only get some java usage text, and the problem persists.

Also tried to add into .bash_profile the line. Again with no success.

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx2g
```

Comment: The `java` command requires as a parameter the name of class that contains the `main` method of the program you are trying to run.

Comment: this works for .exe too? I only have a lib folder for this app, with some .jar. I may know the "main" .jar but how to get the name of the class right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating.

Hello, it worked after a reinstalled the app, and with the export _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx2g on .bash_profile.